# SQL to IQueryable LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hello I am trying to convert the following SQL statement into its LINQ equivalent and since I am really new to .net (coding for one day) i have gotten stuck on this for hours now.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM Books 
 WHERE BookID IN (SELECT BookID 
              FROM Borrows 
              WHERE UserID = 2)
```

This is the model

```
public class LibUser
{       
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Residence"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}

public class Book { 
    [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published{ get; set; }
}

public class Borrowed {
    [Key]
    public int BorrowID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; } 
}
```

I would greatly appreciate anyones help.

EDIT

Context class

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{

          public LibraryContext()
        : base("libromatic")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<LibUser> LibUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Borrowed> Borrows { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Also whether or not you were using it or not avoid using `Select *`

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Yeah I realise that I used that query just for the sake of simplicity when figuring out LINQ

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your context is called `db`, you could do the following query

```
var borrowedBooksForUser = db.Books
     .Where(b => db.Borrowed.Any(x => x.UserID == 2 && x.BookID == b.BookID));
```

Comment: This throws  `System.InvalidOperationException` saying that `The model backing the 'LibraryContext' context has changed since the database was created.` I honestly havent got a clue why its doing it.

Comment: @PavelKašelják It appears that you are using entity framework, and not LINQ to SQL as your question suggested Also it seems you have a schema change in code, that does not yet match the existing database content. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852121/the-model-backing-the-context-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-cre and http://forums.asp.net/t/1998436.aspx?model+backing+the+context+has+changed+since+the+database+was+created+Consider+using+Code+First+Migrations+to+update+the+database for more information.

Comment: This answer is definitely the simplest way to get SQL that will very closely resemble what was given as the goal in the question.

Comment: @Arkaine55, true, although other possible queries exist when using a join condition on the book id that will yield the same result

Answer (score 4):

It might be preferable to do this with a join.

The argument is: If a user borrows huge amounts of books, or there is an error in the data, then your subquery could return a lot of IDs, and SQL 'IN' clauses on long lists can get really slow.

Using a join:

SQL query:

```
SELECT Books.* FROM Books 
  JOIN Borrows ON Borrows.BookID = Books.BookID
  WHERE Borrows.UserID = 2
```

Linq statement:

```
var allBooksBorrowedByUser2 = db.Borrowed
                .Where(borrow => borrow.UserID == 2)
                .Join(db.Books,
                      borrow => borrow.BookID,
                      book => book.BookID,
                      (borrow, book) => book);
```

Comment: This may indeed be a better performing query in the average case.

Answer (score 3):

You Could Do something Like This:

```
var Lnq = new LinqDataContext();
var borrowId = Lnq.Borrowed.Where(a => a.UserID == 2).Select(a => a.BookID).ToList();

var bookQuery = Lnq.Books.Where(a => borrowId.Contains(a.BookID))
                         .Select(a => a.YourColumn);
```

Comment: It complains that the `BookID` doesnt exist in the current context right before the `Contains()`

Comment: @PavelKašelják See The Edit I made, Add the `.Select(a => a.BookId))`

Comment: I did that but it still complains about the `BookID` in this line  `Lnq.Books.Where(a => BookID.Contains` I added the context class to my question

Comment: Just to note the most recent edits have actually made this 2 separately executed queries with the second essentially passing in the results of ("SELECT BookID FROM Borrows WHERE UserID = 2") as a complex where clause. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897630/why-does-the-contains-operator-degrade-entity-frameworks-performance-so-drama

Comment: @Arkaine55 Yeah I was trying to make it more readable for him

Answer (score 3):

Navigation would make everything more simple.

```
public class Borrowed {
    [Key]
    public int BorrowID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; } 

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual LibUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}

Borrows.Where(borrow => borrow.UserId == 2)
       .Select(borrow => borrow.Book);
```

Comment: Doesnt this solution just selects inside the `Borrows` table ? I need to get the books based on what the user has borrowed so I can display the books detail information. I need to join the two tables. And then return the `IQueryable<Book>` not  `IQueryable<Borrowed>`

Comment: Sorry, small mistake I made there, it's not `SelectMany` but instead `Select`. And no, it projects the books... as you'll notice first we search for the books borrowed by the given user Id... then once the search has narrowed down to all the books, it would return `IQueryable<Borrowed>` except out `Select` statement then `projects` the actual `Book`

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
  var getResult=from b in db.Books
  join bo in db.Borrows on b.BookID=bo.BookID
  where bo.UserID=2
```

Comment: can explain what is this and why?