# The model backing the 'XYZ' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am getting following error

**The model backing the 'XYZ' context has changed since the database was created.**

How can get to know the Entity / Entities which are casuing issues for logging purposes?

Comment: Your have to recreate or update database from model

Comment: Which exception type will tell me entity name it's having issues with

Comment: `try { } catch(EntityException){}` But if i where you, i would update EVERYTHING

Comment: This does not catch the exception. It goes to Exception instead EntityException

Answer (score -1):

The entity name you are having issue with is 'XYZ' of course, as it it exactly specified in the error you posted.

Although i'm not sure which exception you have to catch, and you should probably not do it, it is clear what you have to do.

Here is some helpful information :

[The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea)

Also been discused here :

[Entity Framework 4.1 The model backing the context has changed since the database was created, immediately after creating DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931295/entity-framework-4-1-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-since-the-databas)

Where it is told that `catch (PlatformNotSupportedException)` may be related. But has i said, this may not be the solution at all.

Finally, the problem may be even deeper, if it's the case, look at this :

[The model backing the '--Context' context has changed since the database was created - but db is new production database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852121/the-model-backing-the-context-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-cre)