# There is already an object named in the database

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Update-Database failed from Package Manager Console.
I've used Entity Framework 6.x and code-first approach.
Error is

**"There is already an object named 'AboutUs' in the database."**

How can I solve this problem?

```
internal sealed class Configuration 
    : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models.JahanBlogDbContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

My DbContext is:

```
public class JahanBlogDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public JahanBlogDbContext()
        : base("name=JahanBlogDbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<JahanBlogDbContext>());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(t => t.Article).WithMany(t => t.Comments).HasForeignKey(d => d.ArticleId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArticleLike> ArticleLikes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AttachmentFile> AttachmentFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CommentLike> CommentLikes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CommentReply> CommentReplies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ContactUs> ContactUs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProjectState> ProjectStates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProjectTag> ProjectTags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AboutUs> AboutUs { get; set; }
}
```

Package Manage Console:

```
PM> update-database -verbose -force
Using StartUp project 'Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc'.
Using NuGet project 'Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'Jahan-Blog' (DataSource: (local), Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201410101740197_AutomaticMigration.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AboutUs] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max),
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime],
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AboutUs] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AboutUs' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:88b66414-8776-45cd-a211-e81b2711c94b
There is already an object named 'AboutUs' in the database.
PM>
```

Comment: How can I do it (mapping to existing design)?

Comment: @HLGEM, If "well-designed database" can be mapped to an object model using EF than EF is able to generate it too. DB migrations is a powerful tool that makes deployment of your data base easier. I would not recommend avoid using DB migrations. Otherwise patch scripts are needed anyway. I would recommend to use DB migrations right.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

it seems there is a problem in migration process, run add-migration command in "Package Manager Console":

> Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges

do some changes, and then update database from "Initial" file:

> Update-Database -verbose

**Edit:**
-IgnoreChanges is in EF6 but not in EF Core, here's a workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687656/495455

Comment: What does this exactly do? Does this allow the new model to just overwrite the old?

Comment: I started using manual migrations because I use Views as well as Tables in my database. I made the mistake of trying to use automatic migrations and as a result it was trying to create a table from a view. In this scenario your solution does not work, I should instead always use manual migrations. So after doing this I had to undo the changes in source control and remove the "Initial" entry from the _Migrations table.

Comment: This just leads me in an infinite loop: Package Manager Console won't let me do Add-Migration because it gives an error "Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending..." namely the InitialCreate. But if I can't successfully run that Update-Database UNTIL there is also some Initial -IgnoreChanges, then what am I supposed to do??

Comment: Had to use Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges -Force

Comment: Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IgnoreChanges'.

Comment: I get this message: `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: ...`

Comment: @TravisTubbs this ignores the changes you made and "fakes" that your model is synced with the db, with regards to the migration table. You still need to manually sync the two; In my case I removed the changes made to the model, did a Add-Migration, removed the content from the up/down methods before doing update-database - this returned me to the state before the breaking migration. Then I actually re-added the changes, did add-migration, and update-database as usual - this time everything synced

Comment: Check next answer, it may also be because you have `EnsureCreated()` in the Context Constructor: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4649

Answer (score 89):

Maybe you have changed the namespace in your project!
There is a table in your data base called **`dbo.__MigrationHistory`**. The table has a column called **`ContextKey`**.
The value of this column is based on your **`namespace`**. for example is "`DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration`".
*When you change the namespace, it causes duplicate table names with different namespaces.*
So, after you change namespace in code side, change the namespace in this table in database, too, (for all rows).
For example, if you change the namespace to `EFDataAccess`, then you should change the values of `ContextKey` column in `dbo.__MigrationHistory` to "`EFDataAccess.Migrations.Configuration`".
Then in code side, in Tools => Package Manager Console, use the **`update-database`** command.

Another option instead of changing the context value in the database is to hard code the context value in your code to the old namespace value. This is possible by inheriting `DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>` and in the constructor just assign the old context value to `ContextKey`, than inherit from `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext, YourDbMigrationConfiguration>` and leave that class empty. The last thing to do is call `Database.SetInitializer(new YourDbInitializer());` in your DbContext in a static constructor.

I hope your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Awesome, we had exactly this issue !

Comment: Actually this is the real cause of this error. EF is trying to create database as It cannot read which migrations that are applied to database becuse of nameSpace difference

Comment: Thanks this answer, helped me a lot, as Olivier ROMAND said, I had exactly this issue!

Comment: i had no idea it was related to this, but somehow even removing the records of `MigrationHistory` table did not fix it for me... so i dropped all my tables and let EF create all of em all over again, small app, no biggie...but it fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer with details, also good to mention that sometimes misspelling folder name will cause this problem.

Comment: There's no such table. There's a table named '__EFMigrationsHistory' (using ef core) and it doesn't have that column.

Comment: Nope.  Not even relevant.  namespaces haven't changed, and the context key is set manually in the initializer to a static string that has never once changed. -- Data models haven't changed, nothing has changed.

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks a million, I just learnt something now as well :)

Comment: Helped for me. using .Net 5.0 and EF Core. In my case the `__EFMigrationsHistory` holds the filename (not context key) that was used to create the migration. The name of the file has been changed and when `Update-Database` was run the EF see the migration file was not run and it tried to run and failed as the Table already exists. So, I am able to resolve by updating the migration file name in __EFMigrationsHistory table. The table schema is `MigrationId` and `ProductVersion`. I have to update the MigrationId with the correct migration file to resolve the issue. Hope this helps someone! Thanks

Comment: This also happen after renaming migration, in that case just change `MigrationId` in dbo.__MigrationHistory to be same as migration name in code

Answer (score 17):

> "There is already an object named 'AboutUs' in the database."

This exception tells you that somebody has added an object named 'AboutUs' to the database already.

`AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` can lead to it since data base versions are not controlled by you in this case. In order to avoid unpredictable migrations and make sure that every developer on the team works with the same data base structure **I suggest you set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`**.

Automatic migrations and Coded migrations can live alongside if you are very careful and the only one developer on a project.

[There is a quote from Automatic Code First Migrations post on Data Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx):

> Automatic Migrations allows you to use Code First Migrations without
>   having a code file in your project for each change you make. Not all
>   changes can be applied automatically - for example column renames
>   require the use of a code-based migration.
>
> Recommendation for Team Environments
>
> You can intersperse automatic and code-based migrations but this is
>   not recommended in team development scenarios. If you are part of a
>   team of developers that use source control you should either use
>   purely automatic migrations or purely code-based migrations. Given the
>   limitations of automatic migrations we recommend using code-based
>   migrations in team environments.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, my `EFMigrationsHistory` table was emptied (somehow) and when trying to run `update-database` I would get:

> There is already an object named 'AspNetUsers' in the database

After seeing the table had been emptied it made sense that it was trying to rerun the initial migration and trying to recreate the tables.

To fix this problem I added rows into my `EFMigrationsHistory` table. 1 row for each migration that I knew the database was up to date with.

A row will have 2 columns: `MigrationId` and `ProductVersion`

`MigrationId` is the name of your migration file. Example: `20170628112345_Initial`

`ProductVersion` is the ef version you're running. You can find this by typing `Get-Package` into the Package Manager Console and looking for your ef package.

Hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: How did you populate the Model column?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your solutions startup project has the correct connectionstring in the config file. Or set the -StartUpProjectName parameter when executing the update-database command. The -StartUpProjectName parameter specifies the configuration file to use for named connection strings. If omitted, the specified project’s configuration file is used.

Here is a link for ef-migration command references
http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: This answer led me to my mistake, I simply had the wrong project as Startup project.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had re-named the assembly that contained the code-first entity framework model. Although the actual schema hadn't changed at all the migrations table called

```
dbo.__MigrationHistory
```

contains a list of already performed migrations based on the *old* assembly name. I updated the old name in the migrations table to match the new and the migration then worked again.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and after three hours of struggling I found out what was going on

In my case, when I wanted to migrate for the first time, in the `up()` method, the default code wants to create the tables that already existed so I got the same error as you

To solve it, just deleted those codes and write what I wanted. For example, I wanted to add a column so i just wrote

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "fieldName",
            table: "tableName",
            nullable: true);
```

Comment: Looks like a good answer but you might want to check your spelling. You can also use code snippets to make it clear the last line is code. Message me if you want help with this.

Comment: Thanks How can i massage you

Comment: Well done for adding the code snippet @arfa. No need for a massage :) . If you would like to message me just type `@` followed by my username in the comments section.

Answer (score 3):

Delete rows from dbo_MigrationHistory table or delete the table and run

```
update-database -verbose
```

It will run all the migrations in your project one by one

Answer (score 3):

Note: not recommended solution. but quick fix in some cases.

For me, `dbo._MigrationHistory` in production database missed migration records during publish process, but development database had all migration records.

If you are sure that production db has same-and-newest schema compared to dev db, copying all migration records to production db could resolve the issue.

You can do with VisualStudio solely.

1. Open 'SQL Server Object Explorer' panel > right-click `dbo._MigrationHistory` table in source(in my case dev db) database > Click "Data Comparison..." menu.
2. Then, Data Comparison wizard poped up, select target database(in my case production db) and click Next.
3. A few seconds later, it will show some records only in source database. just click 'Update Target' button.
4. In browser, hit refresh button and see the error message gone.

Note that, again, it is not recommended in complex and serious project. Use this only you have problem during ASP.Net or EntityFramework learning.

Comment: This worked for me. It was the other way around, though. My production db had all records in __EFMigrationHistory, while those in dev db where somehow missing (except for the initial one).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was in Seeder. I was calling _ctx.Database.EnsureCreated() inside of it and as far as I understood, the update database command has successfully executed, but then seeder tried to create database "second" time.

How to address:

1. Do nut run update, just start application and call EnsureCreated(). Database will be created/updated
2. Comment out or remove seeder.

Answer (score 2):

Same case (no DB and MigrationHistory table on Server). My steps:

1. I deleted Migration data from Up and Down section of my first migration.
2. Update Database with empty migration (MigrationHistory table was created)
3. Add your REAL migration and update database with it.

Comment: whats is the last step (3) i dont understand how to do that bit?

Answer (score 1):

Another edge-case EF Core scenario.

Check you have a **Migrations/YOURNAMEContextModelSnapshot.cs** file.

as detailed in - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#create-a-migration

If you have tried to manually re-create your database by deleting migration.cs files, be careful that your Migrations/*ContextModelSnapshot.cs file still exists.

Without it, your subsequent migrations have no snapshot on which to create the required differences and your new migrations files will look like they are re-creating everything again from scratch, you will then get the existing table error as above.

Answer (score 1):

same happened with me..
Problem was that Actually i deleted my Database table `MoviesCast` and made new table and problem was that my last migration was trying to induce the deleted table `MoviesCast` in the database.
I Solved it by simply removing all the content of last migration and simply ran Up() & down() method

```
public override void Up()
{
}

public override void Down()
{
}
```

then updated the database and simply add new migration

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted migration folder than you are trying to run "update-database" command on Package manager console ? if so

Just manually delete all you tables
Than run if update-databse(cons seed data will be deleted)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue described in the answer that Elnaz gave.  I had a requirement to change the namespace of the datalayer during a refactoring of our project.  This caused the migrations to not see the existing migrations in the database. I found an excellent answer to this issue that James Chambers blogged.

http://jameschambers.com/2014/02/changing-the-namespace-with-entity-framework-6-0-code-first-databases/

I simply changed the following in the Migration configuration file.

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    this.ContextKey = “Old_Namespace.Migrations.Configuration”;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else in a bind.

Comment: I had similar situation after namespace changes. Tried this fix, but it didn't work still. So I've modified manually namespaces in database table, and then it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute command update-migration -Script. This generate new *.sql script which include all DB changes included in migration. In the end of code are insert commands something like this: INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion]) you can simply run this all INSERT and DB will be synchronized

Answer (score 0):

After more than an hour of not getting any results I tried another approach, not using migrations but I did a schema compare.

In Visual Studio -> Tools -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparison

First I created a new completely new database with EF migrations. Than I did a compare, comparing the new database with the one I wanted to update. Finally generated a migration script, and I could perform a schema update.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (want to reset and get a fresh database),

First I has got the error message : 
`There is already an object named 'TABLENAME' in the database.`

and I saw, a little bit before:

```
"Applying migration '20111111111111_InitialCreate'.
Failed executing DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE MYFIRSTTABLENAME"
```

My database was created, but no record in migrations history.

I drop all tables except dbo.__MigrationsHistory

MigrationsHistory was empty.

Run 
`dotnet ef database update -c StudyContext --verbose`

(--verbose just for fun)

and got `Done.`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same bug as below. Then I fixed it as below:

1. Check current databases in your project:

   - `dotnet ef migrations list`
2. If the newest is what you've added, then remove it:

   - `dotnet ef migrations remove`
3. Guarantee outputs of this database must be deteled in source code: .cs/.Designer.cs files

4.Now it is fine. Try to re-add:
 `dotnet ef migrations add [new_dbo_name]`

5.Finally, try to update again, in arrangement base on migration list:

- `dotnet ef database update [First]`
- `dotnet ef database update [Second]`
- ...
- `dotnet ef database update [new_dbo_name]`

Hope it is helpful for you. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is comment everything in Initial Class,between Up and Down Methods.Then run update-database, after running seed method was successful so run update-database again.It maybe helpful to some friends.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried below solution :
1. deleted create table code from Up() and related code from Down() method
2. Run update-database command in Package Manager Consol

this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Note: I did it because I don't have anything in my database. 
In my case:
 1. I removed a migration by command *remove-migration* in **Package Manager Console** 
 2. Removed database by 'SQL Server Object Explorer' panel > on current database > right-click > Remove
 3. Migrated in **Package Manager Console** write *Add-Migration* and click Enter
 4. The last update by command *update-database*

Answer (score 0):

In the database, query __MigrationHistory table and copy [ContextKey].

Paste it into the DbMigrationsConfiguration ConextKey as below

```
internal sealed class DbConfiguration: DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>
    {
        public DbConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            ContextKey = "<contextKey from above>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue found that connection being used was from a publish profile even though I had changed the connection in appsettings.json. This resulted the migration trying to create a table that already existed. Amending the connection in Connected Services of the project sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you run update-database command it will check __EFMigrationsHistory table records in database with the EfMigration folder items in your project, So if you have a migration item in your project folder that is not exist in database ef core begin to apply those migration in database, eventually you may face with such error.
So compare EfMigration folder items with with __EFMigrationsHistory table in database and make sure both of them are sync and same together, If there is any item in your project that is not in db add it's record in database to keeping sync both together.(actually it may causes becuase you probably truncate your __EFMigrationHistory table in db)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a bit of a one-off/odd case maybe but FWIW I was getting this error as well and the issue came from my AppDbContext.cs having an OnConfiguring() method that was pointing to a different database (which already had the object in it). Using -verbose helped me find this.

I removed the OnConfiguring method but then my Update-Database threw a different error. Eventually I realized I had to keep the OnConfiguring method in my AppDbContext.cs file and include my actual database connection string. This is of course redundant and I realize user/pass info in your code like this is old/not very secure but once I made these changes my Update-Database finally worked w/no errors. My related code below. If anyone has suggestions on how to resolve this in a cleaner way please do chime in.

```
// my appdbcontext.css file 
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass");                
    }
}
```

```
// my program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I wanted to add a new table to an existing database.
My case: First I have create a database (DBShop) by first code approach and I create one table inside it (T_User). Then after I have change my model and I added two more models (Production and Shop), for creating tables inside database for these new two models, I received an error that there is a table inside database T_User.
To solve this problem, after I run Add-migration CreateDB -force, before I update database, I referred to CreateDB.cs file in immigration folder and I deleted the CreateTable method relate to T_User table then I run update-database -verbose.

Comment: This is answer #30. Does it really add anything new? Even if it does, the description is very unclear why you got the error in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The below steps worked for me for the same issue:

**Scenario:**

I was trying to add 2 new fields to my existing model for Email functionality. The new fields are "IsEmailVerified" and "ActivationCode"

**Steps i have followed:**

1.Deleted old migration files under "Migrations" folder which are prevented me to do Update-Database
2.Reverted all my recent changes that i have did on the model

3.Run the below command:

***Add-Migration  -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=**********"***

4.Deleted the contents from Up() and Down() methods from migration file and left the methods empty

5.Run the below command:

***Update-Database -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=***"***

6. After executes the above step, model and DB looks sync.
7. Now, i added the new properties in the model

   ```
        public bool IsEmailVerified { get; set; }
        public Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }
   ```
8. Run the below command:

***Add-Migration  -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=***"***

9. Now the migration file contains only my recent changes as below:

   ```
      public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.UserAccounts", "IsEmailVerified", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.UserAccounts", "ActivationCode", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        }        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.UserAccounts", "ActivationCode");
            DropColumn("dbo.UserAccounts", "IsEmailVerified");
        }
   ```
10. Run the below command:
    ***Update-Database -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient -ConnectionString "Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Custom;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=***"***

11.Now i successfully updated the database with additional columns.

The below is updated table after the recent changes:

[Table after the update migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMTq5.png)

Comment: really do not recommend this, deleting productin migrations will just destroy your environemnts. why would you have to delete your migrations if they worked so far? and you connection strings wont work for every user here, shouldnt run them like that

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have changed the namespace Configuration.cs
There is a table in your data base called `dbo.__MigrationHistory`. The table has a column called `ContextKey`.

```
new namespace  AppData.Migrations { internal sealed class Configuration }
sql command
 update   [__MigrationHistory] set [ContextKey]= 'AppData.Migrations.Configuration'
```

Comment: There are at least two existing answers suggesting this. Please look at other answers first before posting a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also go to edit your last migration `file("201410101740197_AutomaticMigration.cs)` to empty it code inside `Up()`, `Down()` functions.

```
public override void Up()
{
}
public override void Down()
{
}
```

There are some issues that can happen if your DB model (AboutUs model) code is different from DB table (more fields...), then you should remove it from the model code, or you can manually update Up/Down function in the immigration file but keep the difference.

```
public override void Up()
{  
  // Keep difference from model with DB table here
}        
public override void Down()
{   
  // Keep difference from model with DB table here        
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to text formatting

Answer (score -6):

In migration file check the **public override void Up()** method. May be you are trying to create a new db object which is already in database. 
So, you need to drop this object/table before creation of the db object. Just do like bellow-

```
DropTable("dbo.ABC"); 
CreateTable(
            "dbo.ABC",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ..
                 }
```

And now run your migration
      `Update-Database -TargetMigration: "2016_YourMigration"`

Comment: If you do this you'll lose all your data