# There is already an object named'' in the database entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a DbContext like this,

```
     public class EPDContext : TrackerContext
            {
             public EPDContext()
                    : base("name=DevelopmentApplicationServices")
                {
                    Database.SetInitializer<EPDContext>(new EPDDBInitializer());

                    this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
                }

               public DbSet<TaskRevision> TaskRevisions { get; set; }
               protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
               {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<TaskRevision>().HasMany(x => x.Models).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("TaskRevisionID").MapRightKey("ModelId").ToTable("TaskRevision2Models"));


               }
        }



  public class EPDDBInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EPDContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(EPDContext context)
            {
                    //// My Seeding data goes here
                    base.Seed(context);
            }
        }
```

And my Entity:

```
 [TrackChanges]
    public class TaskRevision
    {
        #region properties
        [Key]
        public Guid TaskRevisionID { get; set; } 


        public virtual List<Model> Models { get; set; }
   }
```

and my migration configuration class looks like:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PW.EPD.Data.EPDContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(PW.EPD.Data.EPDContext context)
        {

        }
    }
```

I got this error "There is already an object named 'TaskRevisions' in the database entity framework." when I execute my application. DB has created successfully and there is no seeding data.

At the same time when I execute the same code after removing the **onModelCreating()** override method, db has created with seed data.

What I did wrong here, kindly correct me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you usng automatic migrations?

Comment: Yes, Erkaner, I have enabled automatic migrations in my configuration class.

Comment: Is it related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database?

Comment: then in your migrations configurations file delete the section where it creates this table "TaskRevisions"