# Azure mobile services with .NET backend- There is already an object named in the database

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I have created a .NET backend for a Xamarin iOS app using the Azure portal following this tutorial from Microsoft : [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#create-app)

I then used an existing database, with this new backend. When I try to log into my mobile app however, the log in fails with the above error:

```
There is already an object named in the database
```

The existing database was under a different subscription which will be deactivated. I imported it into the new subscription and set it up.

I have seen tons of similar questions here and have tried some solutions too. I still have the error.

Since I changed the namespace in the new backend,I have read this from an answer here on StackOverflow:

> There is a table in your data base called dbo.__MigrationHistory. The table has a column called  ContextKey.
>   The value of this column is based on your namespace. for example is "DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration".
>   When you change the namespace, it causes duplicate table names with different namespaces.
>   So, after you change namespace in code side, change the namespace in this table in database, too, (for all rows).

I suspect that this might be an issue in my case, but I am currently unable to access my database.

I have also tried this solution which hasn't worked :

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

And lastly, I have tried to use the `update-database` command in the Package Console Extension i Xamarin Studio but I get the error 
:

```
command update-databse not found
```

I'm now not sure how to resolve this issue. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Based on the explanation above regarding changing the context,I already updated this in the `Configuration.cs` class as below:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<testService.Models.testserviceContext>  // new namespace changed here
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
    }

  }
```

So does this update the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table or do I still need to run an update command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by changing the contextKey values for all rows in the `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table based on the explanation above from the answer here by **Elnaz**  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database).I was looking at the wrong namespace, which was pointing to the DBContext. So instead of this :

```
testService.Models.testserviceContext
```

which is from this line:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<testService.Models.testserviceContext>  // new namespace changed here
```

I updated the values in the table to this:

```
testService.Migrations.Configuration
```

which is the new namespace of my Configuration class.

This resolved the issue and I am now able to log into my database.