# Entity Framework Migration creating all tables from scratch

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 and everything is working fine on development database and when I uploaded that build on UAT it is trying to create all tables from scratch and giving SQL Exception.

It is creating all tables and as tables already exists is database the exception is 'There is already an object named 'tblAppointmentBookingPortal' in the database.'

But migration I have not added or made any changes to these table.

Please help!!!

Comment: Have you updated the connection string to match the server's before uploading [

Comment: what is the sql exception ?

Comment: Give more details

Comment: It is creating all tables and as tables already exists is database the exception is  
 'There is already an object named 'tblAppointmentBookingPortal' in the database.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is already an object named in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database)

Comment: This is a poorly asked question. Add these details to the Original question.