# Can't update database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created a table named `USERGOLD` using `Add-Migration` and `update-database` and it works fine the table is created in SQL Server, but now I'm creating another table `FoodMenu`.

I've created a model class and `dbset`, I used `add-migration` and the table is created in the migration, but when I run `update-database` to create the table in SQL Server, it's not working. I get an error

> There is already an object named 'UserGold' in the database

I don't know why the `update-database` are taking my previous migrations.

Contexto:

```
public class RestoContext : IdentityDbContext<RestoUser>
{
        public RestoContext(DbContextOptions<RestoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Menu> Menu { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<Employees> Employee { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employees> Emp { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Manager> Manager { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GoldMenu> GoldMenu { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserGold> UserGold { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FoodMenu> FoodMenu { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
}
```

My migration:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Resto.Migrations
{
    public partial class AddusergoldToDb : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "UserGold",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    userId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Usermail = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    CardNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Validedate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    Amount = table.Column<float>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserGold", x => x.userId);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "UserGold");
        }
    }
}
```

Console app:

```
PM> add-migration AddFoodMenuToDatabase

Build started...
Build succeeded.

To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.

PM> update-database

Build started...
Build succeeded.

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]  
> Failed executing DbCommand (45ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [UserGold] (
          [userId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
          [Usermail] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [CardNumber] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [Validedate] datetime2 NOT NULL,
          [Amount] real NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_UserGold] PRIMARY KEY ([userId])
      );
> Failed executing DbCommand (45ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']  
CREATE TABLE [UserGold] (
    [userId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Usermail] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [CardNumber] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Validedate] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [Amount] real NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserGold] PRIMARY KEY ([userId])
);  
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'UserGold' in the database.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:64024c74-897d-421e-bb48-ef96cb315f44
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
```

> There is already an object named 'UserGold' in the database

Comment: check table _migrations_history and compare which migrations are added.

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: visualy in any database viewer or command line. Check records in the table.

Comment: Have you manually deleted the migration file before? you may show us the migration file `AddFoodMenuToDatabase` after you excuate the command `add-migration AddFoodMenuToDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem in migration process, run add-migration command in "Package Manager Console".

May be your question is dulicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database)