# SignalR notification never reload the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, signalr

I was using signalR to manage database changes, when it happens I want to update the page to other users so that they see the change. But what I've done so far always loads, here is the code:

**INDEX**

```
@section scripts{  
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {  
            var hubNotify = $.connection.Connection4Hub;  
  
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  
                getAll();
            });  
  
            hubNotify.client.GetUpdateData = function () {  
                getAll();
            };
        });  
                          
        function getAll() {  
            var model = $('#dataModel');  
            $.ajax({  
                url: '/Manage/GetUpdateData',  
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',  
                type: 'GET',  
                dataType: 'html',  
                success: function(result) { model.empty().append(result); }  
            });                           
            location.reload();
        }  
    </script>  
}
```

**Connect4Hub**

```
public class Connect4Hub : Hub
    {
        public static void BroadcastData()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Connect4Hub>();
            context.Clients.All.GetUpdateData();
        }
    }
```

**MANAGE**

```
public ActionResult GetUpdateData()
        {
            return PartialView("Partial_Index", db.Matches.ToList());
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I found that the method below is never call, now the page never refresh

```
hubNotify.client.GetUpdateData = function () {  
                getAll();
            };
```

Comment: If it is a new database, with no relevant data, you could just delete it and apply your migrations.

Comment: @AchoVasilev how can i apply my migrations?

Comment: Have you tried this solution?  Also, what version of EF is this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305273/there-is-already-an-object-named-in-the-database#26305974

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you using `location.reload()`;

Comment: i've solved this problem, thanks

Comment: location.reload(); this line is probably ur issue

Comment: Have you tried defining ```hubNotify.client.GetUpdateData``` before you start the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SignalR Hubs API enables you to make remote procedure calls (RPCs) from a server to connected clients and from clients to the server. In server code, you define methods that can be called by clients, and you call methods that run on the client.

In client code, you define methods that can be called from the server, and you call methods that run on the server. SignalR takes care of all of the client-to-server plumbing for you.client can call hub inherited method only.

Call `BroadcastData` methods that run on the server:

```
hubNotify.client.BroadcastData = function () {  
                                        getAll();
                                 };
```

Ref: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)